# How to use Session in Java Servlet?

Tags: java

I am having issues with session in my java code. Upon submitting a form via post, the java servlet will determine if the captcha is correct. May I know anything that I should add to use the session in java servlet? Is there any thing that I need to import to use session?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
try{
    // Validate Captcha
    String userCaptcha = request.getParameter("captcha");
    Captcha captcha = (Captcha) session.getAttribute(Captcha.NAME);
    if (!captcha.isCorrect(userCaptcha)) {
        errorMsgs.add("Please input the correct Captcha value.");
    }
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    ...
}
...
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please give more details. In particular, "I am having issues" is very vague - please explain what you're seeing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you'll need:

```
// create session if one doesn't exist
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

You're not actually referencing a session anywhere in your code.

Comment: Do I need to include HttpSession on "protected doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)"?

Comment: You'll need to import javax.servlet.HttpSession but javac will complain if you don't do that anyway.

Comment: Dunno if it's different because new versions, but now I've had to `import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`, instead of `javax.servlet.HttpSession`, just for the sake of completeness.